# Assembly error when compiling with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm getting "no such instruction" errors when compiling a .s file with this command:

```
$ gcc -s -o scall scall.s
scall.s: Assembler messages:
scall.s:2: Error: no such instruction: `section '
scall.s:4: Error: no such instruction: `global _start'
scall.s:7: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
scall.s:8: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
scall.s:11: Error: operand size mismatch for `int'
scall.s:13: Error: no such instruction: `section .data'
scall.s:15: Error: no such instruction: `msglength .word 12'
```

Here is the code of the file:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov 4,%eax
    mov 1,%ebx
    mov $message,%ecx
    mov $msglength,%edx
    int  $0x80

section .data
   message: .ascii "Hello world!"
   msglength .word 12
```

How can I get rid of the errors?

Comment: Why do you call `gcc` to compile that? `gcc` is a C compiler, use `as` or similiar tool.

Comment: That's what we are using with school right now.

Comment: `unsupported instruction 'mov'` makes no sense.  `mov` from an absolute address is a valid instruction that should assemble, it's just not the one you want.  Recent gcc / binutils only complains about the actual errors (`section` and global, and the missing `:` after `msglength`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following code will compile ("gcc" can compile .s and .S files and link them with C library by default but "as" do the same and don't link code with C library)
as :

```
.section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    mov $4,%eax
    mov $1,%ebx
    mov $message,%ecx
    mov msglength,%edx
    int  $0x80

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
.section .data
    message: .ascii "Hello world!"
    msglength: .word 12
```

gcc:

```
.section .text
    .global main
main:
    mov $4,%eax
    mov $1,%ebx
    mov $message,%ecx
    mov msglength,%edx
    int  $0x80

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
.section .data
    message: .ascii "Hello world!"
    msglength: .word 12
```

Comment: Yes that got rid of the no such errors, but instead I get 

In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11

Comment: if you use gcc you must use main instead of _start.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. When I run it now though I get Segmentation fault(core dumped). Am I pointing at something that doesn't exist?

Comment: I think you must correct following line `mov $msglength, %edx` to `mov msglength, %edx`.

Comment: No I still get the same error. Maybe I should make a new thread for this or mods will be mad.

Comment: You MUST call exit system call (eax = 1) after finishing. i correct the above code for you.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks alot! So AT&T syntax requires $ infront of numbers and variables then I guess. Is the exit system call always required for all system calls or is it only for writing/reading operations?

Comment: Yes, AT&T syntax require $ infront of numbers and variables that you need their address. you MUST exit from every assembly program.

Comment: You don't have to use `main` with gcc.  You can use `gcc -static -nostdlib start.s` to assemble and link a static executable without linking CRT startup files (which defines a conflicting `_start`).

Comment: Also, the better fix for `msglength` would be `.equ msglength,  . - message` to make the assembler calculate the length for you, and use it as an immediate constant instead of loading it.

Answer (score -1):

Correct it as follows and compile it with -c param `gcc -c test.s -o test`

```
.text

_start:
.global main

main: 
    mov 4,%eax
    mov 1,%ebx
    mov $message,%ecx
    mov $msglength,%edx
    int  $0x80

.data
   message: .ascii "Hello world!"
   msglength: .word 12
```

Comment: The right extension for `-c` is `.o`.  You're just assembling without linking here.  And you didn't fix any of the bugs in the asm, and you changed the OP's `_start` to `main`:  use `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static test.s -o test` to assemble+link a 32-bit static executable.